# HD2 WM6.5 compass data

Tags: .net, windows-mobile

does anyone know how to get the compass heading from the HTC HD2?
I have the GPS heading already, but i would like the dugutal compass reading too.
the only place i have found anything near to usefull is here [xda devs hd2 compas api](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=592374) 
the code there seems ok but i cant seem to get it to work :(

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices


Public Class compass

<DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)> _
    Public Shared Function CreateFile _
    (ByVal lpFileName As String, _
    ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Integer, _
    ByVal dwShareMode As Integer, _
    ByVal lpSecurityAttributes As IntPtr, _
    ByVal dwCreationDisposition As Integer, _
    ByVal dwFlagsAndAttributes As Integer, _
    ByVal hTemplateFile As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)> _
Shared Function RegisterService _
(ByVal lpszType As String, _
ByVal dwIndex As Integer, _
ByVal lpszLib As String, _
ByVal dwInfo As Integer) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)> _
Shared Function LocalAlloc _
(ByVal uFlags As Integer, _
ByVal uBytes As Integer) As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)> _
Shared Function LocalFree _
(ByVal hMem As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("coredll.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError:=True)> _
Public Shared Function DeviceIoControl _
(<[In]()> ByVal hDevice As IntPtr, _
<[In]()> ByVal dwIoControlCode As Integer, _
<[In]()> ByVal lpInputBuffer As IntPtr, _
<[In]()> ByVal nInBufferSize As Integer, _
<Out()> ByVal lpOutBuffer As IntPtr, _
<[In]()> ByVal nOutBufferSize As Integer, _
<Out()> ByRef lpBytesReturned As Integer, _
<[In]()> ByVal lpOverlapped As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function

Const DIO_INIT As Int32 = &H3000001
Const DIO_READ As Int32 = &H3000003
Const DIO_QUIT As Int32 = &H3000002
Const INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE As Int64 = -1

Const LMEM_FIXED = &H0
Const LMEM_ZEROINIT = &H40
Const LPTR = (LMEM_FIXED Or LMEM_ZEROINIT)

Structure compass_data
    Public x As Short
    Public y As Short
    Public z As Short
    Public angle As Short
    Public d As Short
    Public dummy As String
End Structure

Public rdBuf(8) As Byte

Overrides Function toString() As String
    Return _
    "X: " + rdBuf(0).ToString + vbNewLine _
    + "Y: " + rdBuf(1).ToString + vbNewLine _
    + "Z: " + rdBuf(2).ToString + vbNewLine _
    + "a: " + rdBuf(3).ToString + vbNewLine _
    + "d: " + rdBuf(4).ToString + vbNewLine
End Function

Private devHandle As IntPtr
Private srvHandle As Integer
Public compassData As New compass_data

Public Function initCompass()
    devHandle = CreateFile("SEN0:", 0, 0, 0, 3, &H80, 0)
    If devHandle.ToInt32 = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE Or devHandle.ToInt32 = 0 Then
        devHandle = IntPtr.Zero
        srvHandle = RegisterService("SEN", 0, "HTCSensorService.dll", 1)
        If srvHandle = 0 Then Return False
        devHandle = CreateFile("SEN0:", 0, 0, 0, 3, &H80, 0)
        If devHandle.ToInt32 = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE Or devHandle.ToInt32 = 0 Then Return False
    End If
    If DeviceIoControl(devHandle, DIO_INIT, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) = 0 Then Return False
    Return True
End Function

Public Function updateData()
    ' Dim readBytes As Integer
    Dim buf(8) As Byte
    Dim result As Integer

    Dim getMemory As New IntPtr()
    If devHandle = 0 Or devHandle = IntPtr.Zero Then Return False

    getMemory = LocalAlloc(LPTR, buf.Length)
    Marshal.Copy(buf, 0, getMemory, buf.Length)
    result = DeviceIoControl(devHandle, DIO_READ, IntPtr.Zero, 0, getMemory, buf.Length, 0, IntPtr.Zero)
    Marshal.Copy(getMemory, buf, 0, buf.Length)
    If getMemory <> IntPtr.Zero Then LocalFree(getMemory)
    If result = 0 Then
        Return False
    Else
        rdBuf = buf
        Return True
    End If
End Function

Public Function shutdownCompass()
    If devHandle <> 0 Then
        If DeviceIoControl(devHandle, DIO_QUIT, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) = 0 Then
            Return False
        Else
            Return True
        End If
    End If
    Return True
End Function
```

End Class